# Event Expresso Paypal paid taxes due to customer after payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, expresso

I'm having a hard time figuring out why Event Expresso mark the taxes paid as Amount due to the customer. I can see taxes on the checkout page and on paypal.

[Event configuration with taxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV1LE.png)
[Result after customer pair the price including taxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqHT.png)

I'm going to google a bit more before leaving work.
If anyone already had this problem please let me know.
Thanks